# How safe is to access this.state inside an event handler?

Tags: react-native, lifecycle

React Native documentation tells in the documentation of `forceUpdate` (which could be thought to be useful to immediately synchronize the last calls to `setState` to the actual `this.state` object to use their values):

> Normally you should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate() and only read from this.props and this.state in render(). This makes your component "pure" and your application much simpler and more efficient.

Does this mean it is unsafe (i.e. perhaps risking using outdated values) to try accessing `this.state` inside of functions invoked as event handlers (e.g. `onScroll`, `onEndReached`, ...) or are those events included inside of the rendering cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot answer your question with confidence, but keep in mind that you can pass a callback to setState, which means that subsequent calls will act on the new state. If you must use forceUpdate you most *likely* try to do something wrong.

> The second (optional) parameter is a callback function that will be
>   executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered.

Comment: This is not what I asked. I asked regarding using this.state in event handlers. forceUpdate is not something I need to use but was an incidental reading in the docs to me (I was reading the component api to learn about the lifecycle).

Comment: Its definitely safe and very common to read this.state inside event handlers. The result of this.state will have the current values.

Comment: @Giannis if you wouldn't mind, updating your answer with this comment to answer the question would have saved me a few seconds